# Auto padding between DIV blocks to always be 100 % of browser window?

Tags: html, css

I have X-number of DIV blocks floated left. When there is no more room on the first "line" it automatically wraps to next "line.

this is the code (JS FIDDLE)

jsfiddle.net/pGfeT/

Anyone know how i can make the white space (padding) between the gray boxes auto so the gray boxes will always be the same size no matter what, just the padding that increases or decreases? (with min-width 5 pixes or so=)

=> CSS

```
.photo-dashboard {
width: 100%;
min-height: 800px;
}

.photo-dashboard .photo-block {
padding: 2px;
float: left;
}

.photo-dashboard .photo-block .blockAlpha60 {
width: 330px;
height: 330px;
float: left;
text-align: center;
/* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
/**/background: rgb(186, 186, 186) transparent;
/* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
background: rgba(186, 186, 186, 0.1);
/* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
/* For IE 8*/
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";

}

.photo-dashboard .photo-block .blockAlpha60 .photo-block-image {
padding-top: 15px;
}
```

=> HTML (see fiddle for working example without angular)

```
<div class="photo-dashboard">
        <div ng-repeat="blobThumb in smallPhotos" class="photo-block">
            <div class="blockAlpha60">
                <img ng-src="{{blobThumb}}" class="photo-block-image" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Note: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please add the code to your question, dont simply wrap the fiddle link in code tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this solution all the blocks are centered so the padding between the boxes don't change but they cover the all center of your page

```
jsfiddle.net/pGfeT/1/
```

It may suit your need if it is for website display, I think it is more conventional to
relatively center your elements than just have an equal padding and elements everywhere on screen, especially for a big screens. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I agree... it's better :)